# std:array indexing and operator[]

Tags: c++, arrays, indexing

Why does operator `[]` work here?

```
int main()
{
    std::array<std::size_t, 10> a;

    // Example with C++23 size_t literal

    for (auto i = 0uz; i != a.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << (a[i] = i) << ' ';

    std::cout << '\n';

    // Example of decrementing loop

    for (std::size_t i = a.size() ; i--;)
        std::cout << a[i] << ' ';

    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

I’m referring to these 2 lines in the decrementing loop:

```
for (std::size_t i = a.size() ; i--;)
    std::cout << a[i] << ' ';
```

As I checked, `a.size()` returns `i=10`, but then `a[i]` is chalked up as 9 instead of 10, so `a[9]` is fine while `a[10]` obviously would not.

So, is `std::array` "fixing" `i` via the `operator[]` index here, under the radar? Otherwise, as far as I tried to edit the code, I can’t see how it comes together.

I made variables for the `i` and `a[i]` values and altered the `for` loop, but it didn't help me understand.

Comment: Let's ask you -- what did you expect to happen when you accessed an item out-of-bounds?

Comment: Accessing an array index out of bounds is *Undefined Behavior*. `operator[]` does not perform bounds checking. But no, `std::array` is not fixing the index.  The loop is simply decrementing `i` before passing it to `operator[]`

Comment: I can see that a[10] is illegal, I 'd expect i = a.size() -1; to apply here and it doesn't. Shouldn't the first iteration take a[10] and crash, instead of changing it to a[9]?

Comment: You're running `i--` before the body of the `for` loop, so `a[i]` would first be evaluated with `i==9`.

Comment: @Rogue The better loop example is an infinite loop.

Comment: @Rogue That would be an infinite loop. `i >= 0` is always true.

Comment: The idiomatic way in current C++ is to NOT use index based for loops (if you don't need indices).  Use [range based for loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), they cannot go out of scope (as long as you don't modify the string in the loop). `for(const std::size_t value : a)`. In C++20 if you want to iterate backward `for(const std::size_t value : a | std::views::reverse)`

Comment: @Rogue (pre C++20) I would recommend : `for(auto it = a.rbegin(); it != a.rend(); ++it){std::cout << *it << "\n";}` again a solution that will prevent out-of-range access

Comment: @interjay Sure i-- happens before the body, but what confuses me is that creating a local variable int whatever=a.size(); before the std::cout << a[i] << ' '; line, whatever turned out to be ==10 still, not 9

Comment: @273K @interjay good catch on the unsigned, seems my loop is _also_ a common antipattern in C++ for decrement. Leaves me wondering if `0xFF...` evaluates to `false` under the hood or if there's some checking of over/underflow flags, but that's a curiosity for me to look into. Regarding the loop, I still hate the posted syntax in the question, though the alternatives almost seem worse, and my suggestion is in fact broken.

Comment: the size of the array is `10`. So `whatever=a.size()` will assign 10 to `whatever`, it has no relation to `i`

Comment: Side note: C++ has a policy of not forcing a program to take a performance hit for anything the programmer didn't ask for. This includes bounds checking, because all of those (mostly unnecessary) checks will add up over time. You will find that because out-of-bounds access has undefined behaviour, some libraries will, usually in a debug build, insert the check and take the performance hit, to help the programmer find bugs.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai you're right, sorry my bad, I thought I had checked i when I was pointlessly checking a.size() instead all the time :/ Now I rebuilt it using whatever=i; and thx it's clear that i--; rules there, sorry again

Comment: for the record the example was taken from here:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t 
where the author dutifully warns against the simpler "naive" deprecated way of going about the decrementing loop to the infinite (and beyond) loop

Answer (score 3):

> So, is `std::array` "fixing" `i` via the `operator[]` index here, under the radar?

No.  `array::operator[]` uses the index it is given, and specifying an index out of bounds is *Undefined Behavior* as the operator does not perform any bounds checking.

The "fix" is being done in the 2nd loop itself, before it calls the `operator[]`.

In the 1st loop, `i` starts at `0` and is incremented *after* being passed to `a[]`.  The loop is doing the *equivalent* of this:

```
auto i = 0uz;
while (i != a.size()) {
    a[i] = i;
    std::cout << a[i] << ' ';
    ++i;
}
```

On the first iteration, `i` is 0, and on the last iteration `i` is 9. So, the 1st loop is accessing array elements at indexes `0..9`.

In the 2nd loop, `i` starts at `10` and is decremented *before* being passed to `a[]`.  The loop is doing the *equivalent* of this:

```
std::size_t i = a.size(), tmp;
do {
    tmp = i;
    --i;
    if (tmp == 0) break;
    std::cout << a[i] << ' ';
}
while (true);
```

On the first iteration, `i` is 10 and then decremented to 9, and on the last iteration `i` is 1 and decremented to 0 (the next iteration breaks the loop without accessing the array).  So, the 2nd loop is accessing array elements at indexes `9..0`.

Comment: thx Remy Lebeau for your thorough explanation. I guess what had me dazzled was the  way the 2nd for loop was arranged, ie the 2nd expression's postscript f--; and the 3rd being void

Comment: A `for` loop in the form `for (init; condition; expression) statement;` is equivalent to `init; while (condition) { statement; expression }` Any of those components can be empty.

Answer (score 1):

Remy Lebeau has [nicely answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78240175/15261315) the question as asked, but also note that you can use reverse iterators to avoid this issue entirely when iterating over a collection in reverse.

```
int main()
{
    std::array<std::size_t, 10> a;

    // Example with C++23 size_t literal

    for (auto i = 0uz; i != a.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << (a[i] = i) << ' ';

    std::cout << '\n';

    // Example of decrementing loop

    for (auto itr = a.rbegin(); itr != a.rend(); itr++)
        std::cout << *itr << ' ';

    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: While this information is true, it is not an answer to the actual question that was asked.  This would have been better as a comment instead.